# socket "/cloudsql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022) Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

Tags: python, django

I have tested connectivity for cloud SQL instance and started web server in sample Django project.

#.\cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances="instance-name"=tcp:5432

## python manage.py runserver

It is working fine in sample Django project.

But whenever We are trying to execute the above commands by our Django Project, we are facinng the following error when execute the python manage.py runserver.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()

File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "C:\Users\KarthikKumar\Documents\GitHub\tnt-deploy\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2_*init*_.py", line 122, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server on socket "/cloudsql/ajrsd2:us-central1:ajrsd2/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022)
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket.

I have checked secrets details in https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manage

There are no restrictions in the access permission.

Also I have verified steps as per the below reference link. Sir
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#console_3

Please check and let us know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.